# JavaScript sort array by key?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with keys like this:

```
0kefsdfsdf
1101fsdf
55fdsfds
```

Now I want to sort that array so that the keys start with the smallest number. Afterwards the keys should look like that:

```
0kefsdfsdf
55fdsf
1101fsdfds
```

I tried this code, but its not sorting the keys:

```
myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a < b;
});
```

How can I sort the array according to the keys so that when I iterate the array afterwards, it starts with the key with the lowest number?

Comment: `.sort` callbacks MUST return: a negative number if a is to be considered less than b, a positive number if a is to be considered greater than b, and zero if they are to be considered equal. You are returning a boolean, which is cast to either 0 or 1 - notably, 1 is returned when a < b, which is the opposite of what you want.

Comment: Also, when people talk about "keys", they usually refer to objects, such as this: `{a:1,b:2}` - here, a and b are keys. In an array, you have values.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/sophisticated-sorting-in-javascript/

Comment: Does every value begin with a number?

Comment: You want sort the keys or the values ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
var sorted = myArray.sort(function(a,b){ return parseInt(a,10)-parseInt(b,10) });
```

This relies on the curious behavior of [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) which isn't worried when asked to parse `"55fdsfds"` :

> If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the
>   specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and
>   returns the integer value parsed up to that point. parseInt truncates
>   numbers to integer values. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.